# Why am I getting my dates as a series of data when I just want them as the X axis?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make charts where I have my first column of data as the  x axis values. It  gives me the results I want for most of my charts but for some it is giving me the dates as a series of data points which I do not want.!/Users/clairespriggs/Desktop/Screen Shot 2019-07-16 at 12.24.56 PM.png

this is what i want the chart to look like
!/Users/clairespriggs/Desktop/Screen Shot 2019-07-16 at 12.52.07 PM.png

```
'Create Charts for Station F Data
DataSheetSF.Activate
Union(Range("A1", Range("I1").End(xlDown)), Range("DV1", Range("DV1").End(xlDown))).Select
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveChart.Name = "Voltage (F)"

DataSheetSF.Activate
Union(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)), Range("J1", Range("Q1").End(xlDown)), Range("DV1", Range("DV1").End(xlDown))).Select
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveChart.Name = "Current (F)"

DataSheetSF.Activate
Union(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)), Range("U1", Range("AZ1").End(xlDown)), Range("DV1", Range("DV1").End(xlDown))).Select
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveChart.Name = "On Potential (F)"

DataSheetSF.Activate
Union(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)), Range("BA1", Range("CF1").End(xlDown)), Range("DV1", Range("DV1").End(xlDown))).Select
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveChart.Name = "Off Potential (F)"

DataSheetSF.Activate
Union(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)), Range("CG1", Range("DT1").End(xlDown)), Range("DV1", Range("DV1").End(xlDown))).Select
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveChart.Name = "Resistance (F)"
```

The First Little paragraph gives me a good chart and then the rest give me the charts I don't want. Just an FYI Column A is the dates and times  column that I would  like as my x  axis

Comment: Can you please upload your screencap to http://imgur.com and link to it?

Comment: how do   i upload images

Comment: Go to http://imgur.com, click on "New Post" (upper left hand corner)